# Using a View in xCode Storyboards but the frame isn't fitting properly

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, subview

I am trying to fit a subview to the bottom of the screen in XCode 5 but it keeps leaving a 20px space at the bottom when running the app.

I've changed the Deltas as well, not sure what's causing it.

My code looks like the following:

```
[bannerView setFrame:CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-bannerView.frame.size.width,
                                [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-bannerView.frame.size.height - [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height,
                                bannerView.frame.size.width,
                                bannerView.frame.size.height
                                )];
```

My Code looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    // Load Ad

   self.bannerView.requestURL = @"http://adsivv.com/md.request.php";
  self.bannerView.delegate = self;



- (void) viewWillLayoutSubViews {

    NSLog(@"bannerView frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(bannerView.frame));

    [bannerView setFrame:CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width-bannerView.frame.size.width,
                                    [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height-bannerView.frame.size.height - [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height,
                                    bannerView.frame.size.width,
                                    bannerView.frame.size.height
                                    )];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Edit - I see what's wrong. The first 2 parameters of CGRectMake() is x and y.
You prob want to keep the x at 0 and shift the y down. You're using the full width and height for those parameters probably placing the view too far to the right. Take a look at it.

This code should place the banner ad view on your screen:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubViews {
    [super viewWillLayoutSubViews];

    [self.bannerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,
                                0.0f,
                                self.bannerView.frame.size.width,
                                self.bannerView.frame.size.height
                                )];

    [self.view bringSubViewToFront:self.bannerView];
}
```

Right before that line:

```
NSLog(@"bannerView frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(bannerView.frame));
```

Then adjust accordingly.

Comment: Also, are you calling your code in -viewWillLayoutSubViews? That's where I'd put it.

Comment: No, I'm not putting my code there Matt. I haven't created that class. You say 'adjust accordingly' but what exactly would I suggest? SOrry for the naiive questions, but appreciate your help

Comment: Okay ive got it working now MAtt, thank you! Except its not showing on iPhone 4 lol. Only on iPhone 5. Is there something I should change programatically?

Comment: -viewWillLayoutSubViews is a method that all view controllers have.  Could you edit your question with whatever is logged with the code I have in my answer? Put it before and after your code.

Comment: Not sure why it isn't appearing at least partially on any other phone size. You'll have to show some logs of the frame size before and after for me to look at.

Comment: It's self.bannerView in the -viewWillLayoutSubviews method right? Just a copy paste error? In your console, what does it log when you run it? Put the logging code after you set self.bannerView's frame for me too.

Comment: I'm not sure what I should paste to you because my console log doesn't seem to show anything related to that. The ad simply loads on iPHone 5 but not iPhone 4. I think its the positioning?

Comment: I read what you said, but I don't know how to edit that in terms of my code?

Comment: Edited my answer again.

Comment: Its still not working lol. Banner doesnt show on iPhone 4 at all

Comment: I edited my code. This should show the banner ad on your iPhone 4. If it works, then we can go from there.